# Converting variables into lists and removing duplicates

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, duplicates

I **scraped** a website using the below code.

The website is structured in a certain way that requires using 4 different classes to scrape all the data which causes some data to be duplicated.

For converting my variables into lists, I tried using the split(' ') method, but it only created a list for each **scraped** string with /n in the beginning.
I also tried to create the variable as empty lists, api_name = [] for instance but it did not work.

For removing duplicates, I thought of using the set method, but I think it only works on lists.

I want to remove all the duplicated data from my variables before I write them into the CSV file, do I have to convert them into lists first or there is a way to remove them directly from the variables?

Any assistance or even feedback for the code would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "https://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory"
api_no = 0
urlnumber = 0

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

csv_file = open('api_scraper.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['api_no', 'API Name', 'Description','api_url', 'Category', 'Submitted'])

#THis is the place where I parse and combine all the classes, which causes the duplicates data
directories1 = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'odd'})
directories2 = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'even'})
directories3 = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'odd views-row-first'})
directories4 = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'odd views-row-last'})
directories = directories1 + directories2 + directories3 + directories4

while urlnumber <= 765:
    for directory in directories:
        api_NameTag = directory.find('td', {'class':'views-field views-field-title col-md-3'})
        api_name = api_NameTag.text if api_NameTag else "N/A"

        description_nametag = directory.find('td', {'class': 'col-md-8'})
        description = description_nametag.text if description_nametag else 'N/A'

        api_url = 'https://www.programmableweb.com'  + api_NameTag.a.get('href')

        category_nametage = directory.find('td',{'class': 'views-field views-field-field-article-primary-category'})
        category = category_nametage.text if category_nametage else 'N/A'

        submitted_nametag = directory.find('td', {'class':'views-field views-field-created'})
        submitted = submitted_nametag.text if submitted_nametag else 'N/A'

#These are the variables I want to remove the duplicates from
        csv_writer.writerow([api_no,api_name,description,api_url,category,submitted])

        api_no +=1

    urlnumber +=1
    url = "https://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory?page=" + str(urlnumber)

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you produced a sample of the data type, structure, etc with the duplicates in it.  (A minimal, demonstrative example).  The general technique here is just to make a set of whatever you have, which will remove true duplicates.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, do you want me to provide a sample of my final data? it it is the case, so I'm not sure it is necessary because just think that I have few of rows from the website 2-3 times each

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't for the api links I would have said just use pandas read_html and take index 2. As you want the urls as well I suggest that you change your selectors. You want to limit to the table to avoid duplicates and choose the class name that depicts the column.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
api_names, api_links = zip(*[(item.text, 'https://www.programmableweb.com'  + item['href']) for item in soup.select('.table .views-field-title a')])
descriptions = [item.text for item in soup.select('td.views-field-search-api-excerpt')]
categories = [item.text for item in soup.select('td.views-field-field-article-primary-category a')]
submitted = [item.text for item in soup.select('td.views-field-created')]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(api_names, api_links, descriptions, categories, submitted)), columns = ['API name','API Link', 'Description', 'Category', 'Submitted'])
print(df)
```

Though you could just do

```
pd.read_html(url)[2]
```

and then add in the extra column for api_links from bs4 using selectors shown above.